# How to extract how many numbers are in a text cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns.
First column represent the range of rented nights of a room.
Second column represent the total number of nights.
The numbers can be between 1 and 31.
How can I calculate automatically on the second column the count of nights ?
Thanks for reading this !

[image]

Comment: Try: `=COUNT(--TEXTSPLIT(A2,{" ",","},,1))`

Comment: @florentin-lupascu if you are using Google Sheets, pls remove excel tag and add google sheets tag. Excel and GS solutions can be different!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `TEXTSPLIT()` & `COUNT()`

[image]

---

```
=COUNT(--TEXTSPLIT(A2,{" ",","},,1))
```

---

Or,

Or in `Google Sheets` as it seems from the screenshot:

[image]

---

```
=COUNT(SPLIT(A2," ,"))
```

---

Another way in `Google-Sheets`:

[image]

---

```
=COUNT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2," |,","|"),"|"))
```

---

- First split by delimiters in `Excel` using `TEXTSPLIT()` (In `GS` using `REGEXREPLACE()` replace delimiters by a `|` pipe, the pipe in between two delimiters it denotes `OR`)
- Lastly, use `COUNT()` function to count the numbers.

---

Comment: Is returning me 0 for some reasons.

Comment: Or, try `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",))+1` I cant say why it is returning `0` for you, unless you show me a screenshot, if you had followed correctly then this should be working.

Answer (score -1):

You could count the number of commas + 1
=COUNTIF(cell, ",")+1

Comment: Is showing me N/A. I'm using Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: im not shure the syntax is 100% correct, its just an idea

Comment: @MrIrrelevant, idea cannot be used as answer.
There are thousands of ideas. You should verify it before posting.